# SIFT object recognition using Laptop camera + ROS

Tags: ros, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I need help to implement SIFT object recognition in ROS with the help of taking images from Laptop camera. Is there any code that is already there for ROS + SIFT object recognition?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55953/sift-object-recognition-using-laptop-camera-+-ros/) by [Bala](https://answers.ros.org/users/4104/bala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sift can be implemented using opencv2 library. Convert your image from a ROS type image to a opencv type image using cv_bridge and then you can use the opencv libraries to implement SIFT. Remember to also include `#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>`. Sift features can be initialized using `cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detect = new cv::SiftFeatureDetector;` and Sift descriptors : `cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> detect = new cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor;` You could replace the word Sift with Surf or Orb for the feature detector. And you could also replace the descriptor with Surf or Brief.

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the search function at ros.org to find:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/blort_ros if you search for sift..

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2